# Video on canvas with panning - how to solve performance issues (also: HTML5, Flash or something else?)

Tags: android, performance, flash, video, html5-video

***Long version:***

I have a very particular issue. I'm a multimedia artist working at the moment together with an animator - we are trying to create an interactive animation that I want to make available online as a website and as free app on the App Store and the Android Market.
But here's the key problem I am faced with now.

The output video of the actual animation will be massive in resolution - probably something like 4 or more times the HD resolution, but it's for a reason. The idea is to let the viewer only watch a part of the video at one time - like when panning around in Google Maps or any other canvas-like view (eg. MMORPG or strategy computer games). So you only see a part of the whole image at one time, and then you can move around to see what's "behind the corner".

So the animation would be a Google Maps-alike canvas (panning *and perhaps zooming if there's enough time to implement it*) but with **video** instead of images.

The big problem that comes up is performance. I was thinking that the best way to make it run would be to scale down the video for different devices accordingly. But then even just considering desktop computers for now - scaling down to 720p for HD screen means there is in total of about 4 times 720p in resolution, which is probably too much for an average computer to decode (Full HD is quite often already problematic) - and the output resolution would be more than the 4K standard (5120 by 2880, whilst 4K is 4096x2160). Anyhow, that is unacceptable.

But I reached the conclusion that there is really no point in decoding and rendering the parts of the video which are invisible to the user anyway (why waste the CPU+GPU time for that) - since we know that only about 1/6th of the full canvas would be visible at any given time.
This inspired an idea that maybe I could split the output video into blocks - something between 8 to 64 files stacked together side by side like cells in a table, then have a timecode timer playing in some variable and enabling the video-blocks on demand. As the user drags the canvas to the visible element it would automatically start the playback of the file at the given timecode read from the global variable. There could be some heuristics anticipating users movement and prematurely activating the invisible blocks in order to remove any delay caused by seeking within video and starting the playback. Then blocks which are no longer visible could deactivate themselves after a certain amount of time.

So my first attempt was to try and see what are my choices platform-wise and I really see it comes down to:

- HTML5 with JavaScript (heavily using `<video>` tag)
- Adobe Flash (using Flash Builder to deploy the apps to all the different devices)

And HTML5 would really be more preferable.

So I did some research to see if it would be at all possible to even synchronize more than one video at a time in HTML5. Unfortunately it's far from perfect, there are two available "hacks" which work well with Firefox, but are buggy in Webkit (the videos often get out of sync by more than a few frames, sometimes even up to half a second, which would be quite visible if it was a single video split into blocks/segments). Not to mention the fact that I have not even tried it on mobile platforms (Android / iOS).

These two methods/hacks are Rick Waldron's sync as shown here:

http://weblog.bocoup.com/html5-video-synchronizing-playback-of-two-videos/

And the other one, also developed by Rick is the mediagroup.js (this one doesn't work in Chrome at all):
https://github.com/rwldrn/mediagroup.js

My test here: http://jsfiddle.net/NIXin/EQbAx/10/

(I've hidden the controller, cause it is always playing back earlier than the rest of the clips for some reason)

So after explaining all that I would really appreciate any feedback from you guys - what would be the best way of solving this problem and on which platform. Is HTML5 mature enough?

***Short version:***
If I still haven't made it clear as to what I need - think of a video zoomed in at 600% so that you can't see everything (some bits are off screen) and you need to pan around by dragging with your mouse (or flicking your finger on mobile devices) to see what's going on in different places of the video. How could I do that (have the video run smoothly) across platforms, while retaining the high quality and resolution of the video?

Thanks a lot, let me know if you need any more details or any clarification of the matter.